# SelectedItem does not change when SelectedItemEvent is fired (ASP.Net DropDown)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP DropDown, declared like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown1" 
    runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The data is filled in this way:

```
DropDown1.DataSource = source;
DropDown1.DataTextField = "Key";
DropDown1.DataValueField = "Value";
DdlCat1.DataBind();
```

"source" is a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> source = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

The selectedIndexChanged method looks like this:

```
public void DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList temp = (DropDownList)sender;
    Console.WriteLine(temp.SelectedValue);
}
```

Now lets say I have item1, item2 and item3 in my dropdown. At the moment i have selected item1. Now the problem is, if i click in item2, the SelectIndexChanged Method is fired BUT the SelectedValue always stays at "item1". So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: fill data source in `page_load` inside the `if(!IsPostBack){//fill your data source here}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where is your data filled? If your data is filled on page load or something then due to the page life cycle you'll overwrite your data source every time